# How I can pass arguments to AsyncTask, and returning results to a field variable from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-maps-api-2

I have a problem with `asynctask` in android Java.
it's the same problem as this : [variable returns null outside asynctask android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457482/variable-returns-null-outside-asynctask-android)
my asynctask get data from a url , to get direction of `google maps` ! 
This is where I call my code , inside onrespondre => myvaraible have data but outside the variable is `null`.

```
    public void onResponse(String status, Document doc, final GoogleDirection gd) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(
                    new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation
                            .getLongitude()))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Position).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    mMap.addPolyline(gd.getPolyline(doc, 3, Color.RED));
    MyVariable = gd.getTotalDurationValue(doc);
}
```

this is the class :

```
    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();

            return builder.parse(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        super.onPostExecute(doc);

        if (mDirectionListener != null) {
            mDirectionListener.onResponse(getStatus(doc), doc,
                    GoogleDirection.this);
        }
    }

    private String getStatus(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);

        if (isLogging) {
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Status : " + node1.getTextContent());
        }

        return node1.getTextContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is null? can you be more specific?

Comment: for example , I declare an object : Integer test; when I affect to my variable test getDistanceValue , my variable test have now a data (let's say it's 8) but if I'm outside of the asynctask , my variable test is null (no data)

Comment: your variable will remain null until the thread inwhich your variable is assigned a value finishes

Comment: @IllegalArgument How I can know how much time the thread takes to finish ? because if I don't solve this problem I can't get the distance or duration in my field variable.

Comment: in your onpostexecute method of your asynctask

Comment: @IllegalArgument okay thanks but I don't know what I must. is it possible to give me an example

Comment: I must use thread.start(); and thread.join(); to solve this problem ?

Comment: @H-Ideas you don't need thread.start or join, just use onPostExecute to work with the variables that you need after the async task has finished.

Comment: @JamieB thank you so much all but the problem I don't know how to do that is there an example in the net or something ? please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `getter setter`s are very basic. But for people who don't know:

A separate class for the getter setter

```
public class getterSetter{

String test;

public getterSetter()
{
    super();
    test= "";
}

public String getStatus()
{
    return test;
}
public setStatus(String input)
{
    test= input;
}
}
```

In your `Asynctask`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        super.onPostExecute(doc);
        setStatus(getStatus(doc));
        if (mDirectionListener != null) {
            mDirectionListener.onResponse(doc,
                    GoogleDirection.this);
        }
```

And in your `onResponse` method:

```
public void onResponse(Document doc, final GoogleDirection gd) {

String status = getStatus();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(
                new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation
                        .getLongitude()))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Position).icon(
        BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

mMap.addPolyline(gd.getPolyline(doc, 3, Color.RED));
MyVariable = gd.getTotalDurationValue(doc);
}
```

Comment: @PiyushGupta: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing as posts are bumped in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do:

Define a getter - setter for the variable that you want.
In your onPostExecute method, set the value of your variable and when you have to retrieve it, get the value from the getter. 
You may use a separate class for the getter - setter.

Comment: you should provide an example or some code snippet if you really need to help out the community.

Comment: When you'r posting your answer then you should keep in mind that if you have already posted a answer then you should edit your answer rather than post a second answer. Enjoy !!@